# Oracle: Need number values converted to text AND preserved

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, oracle12c, decimalformat

If a decimal value is 0.40 I'd like to TO_CHAR(0.40) and get '0.40' back. Likewise, 50 should be to_char'd to '50'.  As simple as what goes in, comes out, but as a CHAR, *in all cases*. So far I've tried the following:

```
select to_char(a, '99D90') test1,
    to_char(a, '90D90')    test2,
    to_char(a, 'FM90D99')  test3,
    rtrim(to_char(a, 'FM90D99'), to_char(0, 'D')) test4
from (
    select 50 a from dual
    union all select 50.57 from dual
    union all select 5.57 from dual
    union all select 0.35 from dual
    union all select 0.4 from dual
    union all select 0.80 from dual
    union all select .88 from dual
)
order by a;
```

returns:

```
TEST1  TEST2    TEST3  TEST4
------ ------   ------ ------
   .35   0.35   0.35   0.35   
   .40   0.40   0.4    0.4    
   .80   0.80   0.8    0.8    
   .88   0.88   0.88   0.88   
  5.57   5.57   5.57   5.57   
 50.00  50.00   50.    50     
 50.57  50.57   50.57  50.57
```

As you can see, what may work in one case doesn't in another. Do I have to test for whole numbers, decimal numbers, then leading and trailing zeros and apply a different formatter for each?  Is there just a simple cast-like construct? (tried cast too btw, similar issues).

---

#### Solved

Oracle does not store or display formatting (even on non-persisted values as shown below). A Formatter must be applied for anything other than that.

Comment: How do you know that your decimal value is `0.40` and not `0.4` or (let say) `0.400`?

Comment: It's entered & stored as such.

Answer (score 1):

`0.4`, `.4` and `0.4000` are all the same. It is just the way you want to display the number.

As I understand, you want to preserve the rows as **string**, and not just **display** them. Then you could handle the conditions using a **CASE** expression.

**TRUNC(NUMBER)** truncates the decimal portion and gives you a whole number. This will be the driving condition.

So, when `TRUNC(NUMBER)` = 0, it means it has only decimal part, and we need to append a zero in the beginning, else just convert it into text.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  select 50 a from dual
  3      union all select 50.57 from dual
  4      union all select 5.57 from dual
  5      union all select 0.35 from dual
  6      union all select 0.4 from dual
  7      UNION ALL SELECT 0.80 FROM dual
  8      UNION ALL SELECT .88 FROM dual
  9  )
 10  SELECT
 11    CASE
 12      WHEN TRUNC(A) = 0
 13      THEN ltrim(to_char(a, '0D99'), ' ')
 14      ELSE TO_CHAR(a)
 15    END text
 16  FROM DATA;

TEXT
----------------------------------------
50
50.57
5.57
0.35
0.40
0.80
0.88

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply.  For a variety of reasons, mostly around comparisons and a complex product,  we need the value IN converted to text and represented exactly after it's been stringified.  I thought there would be a super easy conversion that I was missing.  I know they're all the same number after CAST/TO_CHAR but that doesn't give us what we need.  Even the above solution converts 0.4 to 0.40.  Didn't want a long case statement to deal with every variant.

Comment: @user1351848 You mean the solution I gave is not what you need? Is the output wrong? Could you please let me know how would you want the output in my example?

Comment: Even the above solution converts 0.4 to 0.40. Didn't want a long case statement to deal with every variant.

Comment: @user1351848 I would be happy to help you if you elaborate more.

Comment: All I want is what goes IN comes OUT *exactly* as it went IN but as a string.  Thought it would be the dead simple case, but apparently not.  The example provided takes .88 and converts it to 0.88 and 0.4 to 0.40.  I'm looking for .88 and 0.4.  *Exactly* as it went in.  Make sense?  Many thanks!

Comment: @user1351848 - Oracle does not store string representation of its numeric data fields.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I persisted data.  Makes sense that the behavior of SELECT 0.80 FROM dual mirrors that.  Thanks!